# Background image width is bigger than 100vw

Tags: css

I recently started learning HTML and CSS and practicing on making websites. Yesterday after adding margin top/bottom to sections, my header image got bigger than 100vw. I couldn't figure out what is causing this. And today, even removing margin is not fixing the issue.

Project: https://akinunal.github.io/project-3/

Codes: https://github.com/akinunal/project-3

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it is not bigger than 100 VW you are not calculating 50 px which is the scrollbar.

Comment: Please include code to the question to future proof it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior.
You set a fixed height and width 100vw for div that has a background image with `background-size: cover;`. It means that the bg image should fill the whole div. To preserve image aspect ration browser will scale and crop the image without stretching it.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values):

> If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

PS: in your case, you don't need `width` property at all because of `div` by default has the width 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS: Use 100% instead of 100vw for width.

```
.header-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url(images/slider-image1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of overflow (content is bigger than container), scrollbar appears. Those scrollbars also take space (50 px), without reducing the VW size.